# spring xd table prefix not working as expected

Tags: spring-batch, spring-xd, spring-batch-admin

Within Spring XD I am executing the xd-admin script and the table prefix defined in the server.yml file is not being picked up. Have specified oracle database. All batch job repository tables continue to be created with the default prefix BATCH_.

I have updated the servers.yml to be as follows:

```
spring:
  batch:
    isolationLevel: ISOLATION_READ_COMMITTED
    clobType:
    dbType: oracle
    maxVarcharLength: 2500
    tablePrefix: XD_
    validateTransactionState: true
    initializer:
       enabled: true
```

Is there another location where I need to specify that the default gets overwritten?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, if you want to use a different prefix in Spring Batch you would have to create the batch repository tables manually. If you look at the scripts that are used for creating the tables, they have the BATCH_ prefix -- https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-core/src/main/resources/org/springframework/batch/core/schema-oracle10g.sql

So after creating the tables with the prefix you want, modify the XD config to use the prefix and also turn off `spring.batch.initializer.enabled`.